# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.broker.config.proxy.BarFile

Tags: java, ibm-integration-bus

Added 2 jar files for IBM integration in Java. Getting this exception:

```
error at :: BarFile b = BarFile.loadBarFile("C:\\Users\\Uni\\Desktop\\outputt\\Dev_BAR.bar");

root cause:::::::::

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.broker.config.proxy.BarFile
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
com.cts.XmlExtract.extract(XmlExtract.java:25)
com.cts.BrokerServlet.doGet(BrokerServlet.java:30)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Comment: You need the `BarFile` class added to the classpath.

Comment: thanks for quick reply............from where i can get that file??

Comment: I believe it's located in one of the two jars you're mentioning. Add them both to the classpath and try again.

Comment: i have added those jar file.. import                 com.ibm.broker.config.proxy.BarFile;                      
import com.ibm.broker.config.proxy.DeploymentDescriptor;

Comment: **Importing** is different than **adding to the classpath**.

Comment: how to add them to the classpath then??... right click-- build path-- configure build path--- add external jar...... is this a way of doinf that  thing??? if so, then it is still not working

Answer (score 2):

When developing a java project using an IDE (perhaps IBM's RAD or Eclipse) it is important to remember that there are two classpath that you care about:

1. The classpath when you are writing the code.  This is the Compile Classpath.
2. The classpath when you are running the code on a server.  This is the Runtime Classpath.

The error you are receiving is happening because the Runtime Classpath does not contain one (or both) of the jars that you are attempting to add to your project.

You can add a jar to the Runtime Classpath using one of the following techniques:

1. Add the jar to the WEB-INF/libs directory in your web app project.  This technique guarantees that the jar will be distributed with your WAR file, but also guarantees that the jar will not be shared by other projects that may want to use the jar.
2. If you are building an EAR, add the jar to the EAR file.  It's been a while since I built an ear, so I dont remember the exact directory name (I think you just at it to the root of the EAR).  This allows WAR files that are in the EAR to share the jar.
3. Add the jar to a shared location in your tomcat.  $CATALINA_HOME/lib seems like a good spot.  This allows all web apps in that instance of tomcat to share the jar.
4. Other.  Other servers provide other means to share a jar.